# Result of an if condition comparing a single variable with attributes()

Tags: php, xml, xls

I was trying to understand the following example from w3schools.com: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_editxml.asp

The line which confused me the most is found in the PHP code:

```
if($key == $x->attributes())
```

I have found that `attributes()` produces an array of attribute names and their corresponding values. The `if` statement above clearly is interested only in the attribute name. Is the `if` statement *true*, even if only one attribute name is equal to `$key` ?

Another side question. In the same PHP code, there's the following line

```
$xmlLoad->asXML($xml);
```

Can someone explain why is the latter added?

Comment: No, it's true for every attribute matching and false for those not, it's looping in a foreach

Comment: Given that it's talking about ASP, I have to wonder how old this document is. Either way, as you imply, the bit of code testing key against attributes doesn't look right at all.

Comment: All things being equal, take the W3C tutorials with a grain of salt. Many of them contain incorrect information of teach bad practices. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not surprised, that the example confused you. I hope I can clear it up a little. You probably want the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) to get a better explanation of the steps:
`$xml` is the the name of the xml file and not a string representation as one might expect.

```
function updateFile($xml) {
  $xmlLoad = simplexml_load_file($xml);
```

`$postKeys`is never used. You can ignore, or delete that line.

```
  $postKeys = array_keys($_POST);
```

`children()` returns a `SimpleXMLElement`, but the class is traversable. I.e. you can use it 'like an array' (**not true for all array operations**)

```
  foreach($xmlLoad->children() as $x) { 
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
```

`attribues()` returns yet another SimpleXMLElement, not a string. Thanks to [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php), [loose comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) (==), and the magic `__toString()` of SimpleXMLElement, the if works.

```
      if($key == $x->attributes()) { 
        $x->value = $value;
  }}}
```

If you pass it a file name, `asXML()` does not return the XML content, but writes it to a file. Remember `$xml is a file name. The next line reads the file again.

```
  $xmlLoad->asXML($xml);
  loadFile($xml,"tool_updated.xsl");
}
```